# jasper studio 6.3.0 hyperlinks

Tags: jasper-reports

Can a report contain hyperlinks that point to a URL or an external software  so that when those hyperlinks are clicked, the user will be taken directly to that software or URL which allows the user to view/edit the report directly?

P.S. 
I am using Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Place a `Text Field` on the report.
2. Select the text field.
3. Set **Expression** the text that the user reads for the hyperlink (e.g., anything but "Click Here!")
4. Click the **Hyperlink** button on the **Properties** panel (depending on the screen resolution of your monitor, you might have to expand the panel to see the button).
5. Expand **[+] Hyperlink**.
6. Set **Link Target** to: Self
7. Set **Link Type** to: Reference
8. Set **Hyperlink Reference Expression** to a string with a fully qualified HTTP GET request URL (e.g., `"http://company.com/reports?id=12345"`).
9. Run the report.

For PDF and HTML versions (and possibly Excel?) the report will contain a clickable hyperlink.

From there, that fully qualified HTTP GET URL can point to a web application that provides a download link for that report (e.g., by reading the `id=12345` value given by the hyperlink).